# Google map with two Fusion Table layers does not display second layer

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I have a map that is displaying two fusion table layers. I have styled them both using the `styleId` attribute to take the styles defined in the Fusion Table UI instead of using the `styles` attribute when creating the layer in Google maps. From the [maps docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#fusion_table_styles), it mentions that you can have up to 5 fusion table layers, with one of them being styled.

> Styles can only be applied to a single Fusion Tables layer per map. You may apply up to five styles to that layer.

What I'm not 100% clear on is if this applies to inline styles only, e.g.:

```js
layer1 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  query: {
    from: table1Id
  }, 
  styles: [
    {markerOptions: {iconName: 'red_blank'}, where: 'age > 50'},
    {markerOptions: {iconName: 'grn_blank'}, where: 'age <= 50'}
  ]
});

layer2 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  query: {
    from: table2Id
  },
  styles: [  // This won't work because you can only style one table inline
    {markerOptions: {iconName: 'red_blank'}, where: 'age > 50'},
    {markerOptions: {iconName: 'grn_blank'}, where: 'age <= 50'}
  ]
});
```

or if it also applies to styles defined in the fusion table UI:

```js
layer1 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  query: {
    from: table1Id
  }, 
  options: {
    styleId: 2,   // Obtained from the fusion table UI
    templateId: 1 // Obtained from the fusion table UI
  }
})

layer2 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  query: {
    from: table2Id
  }, 
  options: {
    styleId: 2,   // Obtained from the fusion table UI
    templateId: 1 // Obtained from the fusion table UI
  }
})
```

From my reading of the docs, it would seem that it's only the first type that is not allowed on multiple layers.

The `styleId` way of styling a table is actually not mentioned in the Google Maps docs, but this is the way the embed code generated in Fusion Tables when you "Publish" a map looks like, and it actually works for individual layers.

If I enable both layers (`layer1.setMap(map)`), only one of the layers gets displayed. If I disable a layer, the other one appears correctly.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you  really use the same variable-name `"layer"` for both layers? variable-names may not be shared, 1 layer will overwrite the other layer.

Comment: No, I use different variables. I was just illustrating the two syntaxes I've used. I'll update the examples for clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with mixing inline-styles and `styleId`.

Demo with 5 layers, 4 layers use styleId and 1 layer uses 5 inline-styles , as  you see the result is as expected 9 different styled markers: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/Zk2CE/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/Zk2CE/)

The problem with your attempt: you are always using the same `where`-clause in the `query`(currently there is no `where`-clause, all rows will be selected).

When you define a `where`-clause in a style this will apply the style to the selected items, to all other items(that will not be matched by any `where`-clause in a `style`) the default-style will be applied(e.g. a red dot for a marker)

The result: when specific rows(items) will be selected by the `query` of more than 1 layer, only 1 `style`/`styleId` may be applied to these items(usually the style set with the last layer that has been added to the map).

Comment: I am using `where` clauses in my actual code. I was just trying to simplify it for the example (I am pulling from two different tables, one with polygons and one with markers). From your example, however, it is obvious that it should be working. I will try to replicate my scenario in a JSFiddle to see if I can spot what I'm doing differently.

Comment: Hmmm I created a minimal version on JSFiddle with my own code, and styles seem to be applying correctly. I think in the end it might have been due to a Fusion Tables bug I encountered earlier in the week (around the same time this started happening), where changing the styles in the Fusion Tables UI did not generate a new styleId. After contacting support, they said it was a known issue and that I would have to add a new Map tab in order to work around this. Thanks for motivating me to write the minimal code in JSFiddle @Dr.Molle!